# How to fix error Exception: Can not be converted to int

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use the Property Service as an analogue of the vlookup function here is my code

```
function setUpProps() {
  console.log('Set up props');
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  documentProperties.deleteAllProperties();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shname = sh.getSheetByName('конфиг');
  var values = shname.getRange(2, 1, shname.getLastRow(), 7).getValues();
  props = {};
  for (i of values) {
    props[i[0]] = i.slice(1).join(";");
  }
  documentProperties.setProperties(props);
}

function getProps() {
  var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  Logger.log(props.getProperties());
}

function onEdi(e) {
  var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet()
  var row = range.getRow()
  var shName = e.source.getSheetName();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var g = 'г';
  if (['мука', 'масла', 'жмыхи', 'десерты', 'лечебные тарвы'].includes(shName) && col == 2) {
    var arr = [];
    var itemNames = range.getValues();
    for (let name of itemNames) {
      var data = props.getProperty(name + g);
      Logger.log(name + g);
      var weight, width, length, height, dimensions, volume;
      if (data != null) {
        [weight, width, length, height, dimensions, volume] = [...data.split(';')]
        var row = [weight, width, length, height, dimensions, volume];
        Logger.log(row);
        arr = arr.concat([row]);
        Logger.log(arr);
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(row, 21, range.getNumRows(), 6).setValues(arr);
  }
}
```

error getting in this place `sheet.getRange(row, 21, range.getNumRows(), 6).setValues(arr);`

`Exception: Невозможно преобразовать "500,120,80,250,120х80х250,0.0024" в int. at onEdi(Copy of PropertyService:43:11)`

On function `onEdi()` I'm set a installable trigger for edit

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8EoY.png)

When I use similar code like this

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    const itemCol = 3;
    const groupCol = 4;
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet()
    var row = range.getRow()
    if (range.getColumn() == 2) {
        var itemIDs = [];
        var itemGroups = [];
        var itemNames = range.getValues();
        for (let name of itemNames) {
            var data = props.getProperty(name);
            var itemID, groupName;
            if (data != null) {
                [itemID, groupName] = [...data.split(';')]
                itemIDs.push([itemID]);
                itemGroups.push([groupName]);
            } else {
                itemIDs.push(['NO DATA']);
                itemGroups.push(['NO DATA']);
            }

        }
        sheet.getRange(row, itemCol, range.getNumRows(), 1).setValues(itemIDs);
        sheet.getRange(row, groupCol, range.getNumRows(), 1).setValues(itemGroups);
    } 

 }
```

it works flawlessly
A simple trigger for edit is also used here

But I want to insert data in an array, tell me where is my mistake?

Gif what I need to output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNBCj.gif)

Comment: About your question of `But I want to insert data in an array, tell me where is my mistake?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue and your expected result. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, can i give you access to the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike, I add gif for output data

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply and the additional information, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike,  [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19yp5vKuKRpQQH5tMiTfSaGGiQI5OPSfbLZLY9B-Oc7U/edit#gid=0) perhaps an example will help you

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `example perhaps an example will help you`, when I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do. I apologize for my poor English skill. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: @Tanaike, second [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNp6-_vqZ2O6x-3PmNK6-0uY1LXQJ8yYFaJo2Elp0k0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `second example`, when I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. In your provided Spreadsheet, where can I see your input and output situations?

Comment: @Antonio, can you show or give a clear example of the output you want to achieve? I can't understand and see clearly the gif you've shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining `row`.

On line 3 of `onEdi(e)`:

```
var row = range.getRow()
```

But on line 23 of `onEdi(e)`:

```
var row = [weight, width, length, height, dimensions, volume];
```

So in your loop `row` is redefined from an integer to an array.

You could change it to

```
let row = [weight, width, length, height, dimensions, volume];
```

Now there would be two variables named `row`, one at a global scope for the `onEdi(e)` function and one at the local scope of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I should be a little more careful